# Building A Social Network

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, firebase, social-networking

So, I'm starting out building a social network web app. I'm looking into how to fit the parts of my stack together and I'm looking for some guidance about what various frameworks will allow me to do. My current stack idea is to have:

- Firebase JSON API: serving user, post, comment, and all the other data
- [EmberFire](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire): to plug that API into EmberJS
- EmberJS: my front-end MVC (because I'm new to MVC and Ember seems the most accessible)

What I'm stumbling on at the moment is how I'm going to implement users with this stack. I've looked at [basic authentication stuff](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-1) but I haven't found anything that would allow me to allow certain actions and views for certain users and not others - the basics of a social network really.

Is it sensible to be doing this stuff in front-end MVC? If so what should I be using to do authentication/personalisation? If not, should I just be doing a PHP/SQL setup? I'd rather avoid that because my skills are all front-end.

Comment: If I understand you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzasJuhsTSs at around 4:00 this guy talks about keeping that logic in the backend, while all the front end does is show or hide certain elements based on that data (something like {{#if user.canUpload}} link to uploads {{/if}}

Comment: I guess one problem with keeping that logic on the front end is - users can 'hack' the front end, so you still need the server to keep track of what someone can and cannot do

Comment: Firebase provides authentication with many popular OAuth providers and allows you to define granular data access (read/write) rules. So if you can change your requirements from "users can only take certain actions/see certain views" into "users can only read/write certain data", you're a long way.

Comment: @user1479059 are you saying you can't have business logic in Firebase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you are just getting started, Firebase is a great service to learn on due to their 'back end as a service' model - you will spend more time building/modeling your data and less time running/installing. Not that you won't want to learn more about that later, but it lets you focus on one piece at a time.
2. From an access perspective, JS/NoSQL vs PHP/MySQL isn't going to be the issue. They each have their own security requirements - it's more that PHP/MySQL has had more time to establish those rules. Additionally, Firebase being a hosted service has it's own set of requirements.
3. Firebase security rules are a little weird when you first look at them, but they begin to make some sense after you sit with them for a bit. The Firebase docs are actually a pretty great resource. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/
4. Basically, if you use a Firebase 'login provider' it makes Firebase act as both a database and a authentication manager, and the combo helps keep users 'fenced' to where you want them. You can use data from other paths, variables, validation rules, etc. You can even make a 'custom login provider' if you need to integrate with an existing one.
5. Finally, on the client end, your view can respond to whatever Firebase returns - if a user does 'hack' their way through to a page they shouldn't be on client side, no data is returned anyways and no submitted information would be allowed because of the rules.